# usort doesn't behave as expected

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a simple two-dimensional array:

```
$users = array(
    array('user' => 'John', 'points' => '0'),
    array('user' => 'Paul', 'points' => '0'),
    array('user' => 'George', 'points' => '0'),
    array('user' => 'Ringo', 'points' => '0')
);
```

I need to sort them by `points (DESC)` and then by `name (ASC)`.
This would be my code:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    if($b['points'] == $a['points'])
        return $a['user'] - $b['user'];
    else
        return $b['points'] - $a['points'];
}

usort($users, 'sortByOrder');
```

I get the original order instead of an alphabetical order (since they all have 0 points currently). Why?

Comment: Users are not countable. Check the boolean that is returned.

Comment: What is `John` minus `Paul`? or `Ringo` minus `George`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [array_multisort](http://php.net/array_multisort):

[DEMO](https://eval.in/585380)

```
$users = array(
    array('user' => 'John', 'points' => '0'),
    array('user' => 'Paul', 'points' => '0'),
    array('user' => 'George', 'points' => '0'),
    array('user' => 'Ringo', 'points' => '0')
);

$sort = array();
foreach($users as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['points'][$k] = $v['points'];
    $sort['user'][$k] = $v['user'];
}

array_multisort($sort['points'], SORT_DESC, $sort['user'], SORT_ASC,$users);

print_r($users);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => George
            [points] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => John
            [points] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user] => Paul
            [points] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user] => Ringo
            [points] => 0
        )

)
```

And this [DEMO](https://eval.in/585384) with different points

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php), So your function should look like this

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    if($b['points'] == $a['points'])
    {
        return strcmp($a['user'], $b['user']);
    }
    else{
        return $b['points'] - $a['points'];
    }
}
```

Check here: https://eval.in/585383